# Magento data from M1 to M2

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, magento-community, data-migration

I need to know is there any way, i can migrate data from magento 1 to magento 2, I have already did this before, but it was about few months back, now my M1 site has some new data, which i need in M2.

Is there any way, so that i can only get that data which is not present in M2 from M1.

Comment: You can use delta migration for the same. It will update only required data. Reference: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/migration/migration-migrate-delta.html

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, is there is any way i can do this with mysql?

Comment: I think no because magento data are stored in many different tables. So you should  use migration tool.

Comment: ok, I am curious to know is there any way we can migrate only data which is not present in M2 from M1 apart from delta migration?

Comment: my question is, if there is any other way of migration of data apart from delta method?

Comment: I did some research and found out this thing, https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/228/#issuecomment-278967142

really need to know, if there is any other of migrating data apart from delta migration?